# StreamBuilder InitialData and Stream Control

Tags: stream, flutter, behaviorsubject, rxdart, stream-builder

Here is the BLoc that has my BehaviorSubject and getters for stream and latest stream value.

```
  Stream<User> get currentUser => _currentUserSubject.stream;

  User get currentUserValue => _currentUserSubject.stream.value;

  final _currentUserSubject = BehaviorSubject<User>();
```

Here is the StreamBuilder that uses these currentUser as stream source and currentUserValue as initialData:

```
StreamBuilder<User>(
        initialData: _loginAuthBloc.currentUserValue,
        stream: _loginAuthBloc.currentUser,
...)
```

I make sure that currentUser has a latest value when the page which returns this StreamBuilder is opened. But because It has some waiting duration before this stream is subscribed and latest value is returned, I set the initialData with currentUserValue so that makes sure that we skip that waiting part. So far so good. Buttt the thing is I want to ignore the value that is coming after stream is subscribed and after waiting that stream's latest value is also coming and it is the same value as initialData. Do you have a suggestion about this?

Comment: You currently cannot avoid that due to a limitation with StreamController. I have some plans to fix it, but that's not available yet

Comment: Yeah you told about implementing my own StreamController but I have no idea how to do that. I found this issue which is similar to mine I believe. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16465 Please let me know when you're done.